# Storing timezone aware datetimes with Django 1.6 and PostGreSQL 9.2

Tags: django, postgresql, time

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris' # UTC+1
USE_TZ = True
```

**I just want to have all my datetimes TZ-aware in database**, but I'm not sure what is the right way to do it, even after reading django doc.

1) First, I tried to use `timezone.now()` everywhere.
If It's 12:19 in Paris, it will return:
`datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 11, 19, 51, 842247, tzinfo=<UTC>))`

It seems to be the normal behaviour: Django converts the datetime to UTC, but not sure if it's a good thing. Am I not losing some data in the process? How to know that data is related to the Paris timezone this way?

2) Then, I tried to use `localtime(timezone.now())` everywhere.
This time, if it's 12:19 in Paris, I get a: `datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 12, 19, 37, 372710, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CET+1:00:00 STD>)`

Here, the datetime is not converted, and the real timezone info (Paris) is stored into the datetime. I thought is was better, but after some searches, no one seems to process this way. Am I missing something?

Plus, with the second solution, I really expected my objects to be stored in PostGreSQL database with `+01` suffix. Not at all.
Here is the content of my DB timestamps: `2016-03-16 11:19:01.093176+00`

I don't understand how to do all this stuff the right way.

Comment: What locale do you use in system, Django applicaton and Postgres instance?

Comment: System (ubuntu) : "en_US", Django : LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'. Postgres: didn't check, the default one. Not sure however if this is closely related to my problem?

Comment: Datetime settings? Could you perform command `locale` in a shell?  Sometimes it can be related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/)

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime
>   information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime
>   objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in
>   templates and forms.

So when you save time in database it is stored in UTC automatically by Django. When you render this time in templates or forms, it is automatically converted by Django to user's timeozone or default timezone (`TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'`) from your settings.

And this is valid for Django 1.4 and above.

**To answer your questions:**

> Django converts the datetime to UTC, but not sure if it's a good thing.

It is a good thing as it provides consistency, you now that all of your datetime values stored in the database are in UTC. So any time or timezone manipulation will be very easy against an approach where you will have to consider timezone for each of your record.

> Am I not losing some data in the process? How to know that data
>   is related to the Paris timezone this way?

Why is it important for you to know in which timezone time was entered? Isn't it enough to display time in desired timezone (Django will automatically do this and convert from UTC to your timezone). If it is important to store timezone info then you need to store it in a separate `Char` type field in the model.

> Here, the datetime is not converted, and the real timezone info
>   (Paris) is stored into the datetime. I thought is was better, but
>   after some searches, no one seems to process this way. Am I missing
>   something?

Again, when Django does this for you why would you want to do it yourself? That is why no one does this way. Plus it is a good practice to store time in standard UTC time for it to be easily convertible to any other zone.

Comment: I know about this as I said "It seems to be the normal behaviour". I read the doc too. But that does not answer to my questions :(

Comment: Thanks, this is much clearer to me now :) I guess I'll follow the standard timezone.now pattern.